# React Redux useEffect not loading data on initial page render

Tags: redux, react-redux, use-effect

I'm trying to render a quiz object from an api and am using useEffect to do so, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my Quiz component:

```
export function Quiz(props) {
  const { 
    quiz, 
    fetchQuiz,
  } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchQuiz();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div id="wrapper">
      { quiz.question }
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    quiz: state.quiz,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  fetchQuiz,
})(Quiz)
```

my action creator:

```
export function fetchQuiz() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios. get('http://localhost:9000/api/quiz/next')
        .then(res => {
          dispatch({ type: SET_QUIZ_INTO_STATE, payload: res.data })
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }
}
```

my reducer:

```
const initialQuizState = null
function quiz(state = initialQuizState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SET_QUIZ_INTO_STATE:
      return action.payload
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

So when I console.log "quiz" in my Quiz component, I get the object that I am expecting and it's all good. But when I try and call "quiz.question" I get the error: Cannot read properties of null (reading question). Which leads me to believe useEffect is not loading the data from the api correctly. Am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: have you added the quiz reducer to the redux store? and where did you console.log 'quiz'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing an object from an API response in the DOM, make sure you have a conditional to check for completion like so:

```
  return (
    <div id="wrapper">
      { quiz ? quiz.question : 'No Quiz Here' }
    </div>
  )
}
```